# How to give ID for TableRow using insertRow()?

Tags: javascript

```
 var table = document.getElementById("table1");
    var tr = table.insertRow();
    var td = tr.insertCell();
    td.innerHTML= document.getElementById('txt1').value;
```

i am using code like this. how to give Id for tr(TableRow). help me.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just give
tr.id = "some_id". This will work.

Answer (score 7):

because you use standard Javascript you have to use the function `setAttribute("align", "center", 0);`.

Try following:

```
tr.setAttribute("id", "myIdNameforThisRow", 0);
```

Comment: Is there a reason `tr.id = 'value';` won't work? It's what I always do when I `document.createElement()` and it works just fine - won't it work with `insertRow()`?

Comment: In your way the attribute has to be exists, else the browser returns an error (Error: Operation on an undefined value). Only the programmers of the browser know why it does not work.

Comment: Why can I add custom attributes and methods to HTMLElement objects by directly naming them, then? I have just been playing with this and I cannot get it to break anywhere...

Comment: Don't ask me that. I had gone often in the same trouble when I tried to add the 'src' attribute to an iframe. Whatever the browsers (IE, FF) hadn't accepted it.

Comment: I'm confused. But I am probably going to start using setAttribute instead. And give you an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

```
var table = document.getElementById("table1");
var tr = table.insertRow();
tr.id = 'id_for_this_row'; // Just assign a value to the new row's 'id' attribute
var td = tr.insertCell();
td.innerHTML= document.getElementById('txt1').value;
```

Comment: I have never had that problem, try @reporters solution - do you have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

create a variable first like var id=0;

then

```js
tr.id=id;
id++;
```

use this code