# Adding id to html table row in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

The rows in my table have unique id, example: `<tr id = "tb6">`
I am appending new rows by javascript in this way:

```
var table = document.getElementById(f);
var row = table.insertRow();
var cell1 = row.insertCell();
var cell2 = row.insertCell();
cell1.innerHTML = text1;
cell2.innerHTML = text2;
```

How do I add id to this newly created row in vanilla javascript (not jquery).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7160897/how-to-give-id-for-tablerow-using-insertrow

Comment: Why to set an id, rows already have an id, `row.rowIndex` ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
row.id = "foo";
```

or

```
row.setAttribute("id","foo");
```

Comment: OP says: "I am appending new rows ..." Presumably the code is in a function, which is reused, and they want an unique id ...

Comment: @Teemu *"How do I add id to this newly created row"* I read it as the OP had no clue how to set an id. It is not that hard to add a counter...

Comment: Teemu, Epascarello, I had no clue how to set the id. Yes, I am using this in a function and the id will be assigned using a counter.

Answer (score 3):

First off, it is a really bad practice to have a unique ID for each table row. If you want to identify the table row, you can do that based on the data itself. Look at the concept of event bubbling. It is best to use the event.target and event.currentTarget to identify for which row you are firing the event. If you want to set an id for what you have, you can do this:

`var table = document.getElementById(f);
    var row = table.insertRow(); 
    var cell1 = row.insertCell();
    var cell2 = row.insertCell();
    row.id = "xyz"; //you can add your id like this
    cell1.innerHTML = text1;
    cell2.innerHTML = text2;`

However, I must advise you it is a VERY BAD PRACTICE to use unique IDs for rows

Each row cannot be set a unique id every time. The idea is to utilize a naturally occurring phenomenon of event bubbling. So might as well use it. As the application scales itself, the ids have to become more and more versatile and that is a hassle in itself.

Comment: Why is it *VERY BAD PRACTICE*?

Comment: Each row cannot be set a unique id every time. The idea is to utilize a naturally occurring phenomenon of event bubbling. So might as well use it. As the application scales itself, the ids have to become more and more versatile and that is a hassle in itself.

Comment: You should consider adding that to your answer now. I was merely trying to get you to explain why it is bad as you claimed it is bad.

Comment: @KatakamNikhil Perhaps you've meant static ids for rows are bad practice? Btw. the id you've set in your example is not unique.

Comment: Nikhil, the rows contain data that are manipulated using ajax. Giving ids to each row may be bad, but that is the only way I know.

Comment: @sridhar if the ids are what you need, you can identify the specific row completely by the event.target and event.currentTarget. 
I suggest you go through these to understand this well.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: @Teemu I set the ID to demonstrate how he can set the IDs on elements. Not trying to make dynamic ids on my own

Comment: @KatakamNikhil It was just a nitpick. Actually I pretty much agree with you about using ids for table rows.